# Doctrine custom repository methods and unmanaged entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine, dql

I've got custom entity repository (let's say `CategoryRepository`) that returns Doctrine entities. I also have newly created entity (let's say `Product`) that I want to persist.
Product is related to Category and, in that case, Product is the owning side of the relationship so I've got following code:

```
$category = $categoryRepository->customGetCategory($someCriteria);
$product = new Product();
$product->setCategory($category);
$em->persist($product);
```

and result is

> [Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException]
>   A new entity was found through the relationship
>   'Acme\SomethingBundle\Entity\Product#category' that was not configured
>   to cascade persist operations for entity: blahblah. To solve this
>   issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown
>   entity or configure cascade persist  this association in the mapping
>   for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"})

For now I'm aware that all entities returned by custom repository methods using `\Doctrine\ORM\Query::getResult()` method where Query object is returned by `EntityManager::createQuery($dql)` factory method are detached by default. So I've got entity returned by repository that exists in database and I can't find a way for doctrine to have it managed just like any entity returned by f. ex. `$repository->findBy()` method.

Could anyone point me in right direction with this? I'd really like to solve that, it's killing me.

Comment: could you please post your Category and Product entities? (only the code snippets of the relation between them)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably one of the top 5 Doctrine questions asked.  Just difficult to search for.  Could try searching on the error message.

The problem is that Category::setProduct is never being called.  Update your Product entity with:

```
class Product
{
    public function setCategory($category);
    {
        $this->category = $category;
        $category->setProduct($this); // *** Add this
    }
}
```